# Capping an old refrigerator water line?

Tags: water

My old fridge broke down, and I am getting a new one but this one does not have a water/ice dispenser. I turned off the water line to my appartment to disconnect the old fridge, but before I can turn it back on I need to cap it somehow? Is there something I can use? Attached is the picture of what it looks like

[image]

Comment: Why would you turn it back on? Just leave it off... That valve only feeds the fridge, just turn that white valve to off and leave it.

Comment: Ah. I'm having trouble moving the white valve, the entire unit seems to move as opposed to it shutting off

Comment: @RonBeyer is correct in that you only need to turn the valve off. They can stick a bit  so they will require some force. You'll need to support the outlet part as you turn the handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a 1/4" cap, but buy plenty of different sizes and return what you don't use. Use teflon tape on the threads.

You might also try grabbing the valve with slip joint pliers and turning the white lever.

It would be better if you could disconnect/cap at the source, but if it's a rental, I'd understand your reluctance.

Answer (score 0):

I capped mine. I wrapped it with plumbers tape, then capped it with a 1/4" cap from Home Depot.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.